# Many to Many Relation with EF 6 CRUD

Tags: entity-framework-core, many-to-many, ef-core-6.0

I'm New to EntityFrame work, and I'm Just trying to get experience by working on projects, I searched a lot on the web but unfortunately there is no much example about this for EF6.
I have 2 tables `Movie` and `Actor` with many to many relationship as below:

Actor Model:

```
public class Actor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public DateTime BOD { get; set; }

    // RelationShip
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Movie Model:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public GenresEnum Genre { get; set; }
    public int ReleasedYear { get; set; }
    public string PosterUrl { get; set; }

    // RelationShip
    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to add data to the `Movie` and I need to add the movie data and multiple actor (each movie have more than one actor) so I created a DTO called `MovieRequestDto`

```
 public class MovieRequestDto
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public GenresEnum Genre { get; set; }
    public int ReleasedYear { get; set; }
    public string PosterUrl { get; set; }

    //// RelationShip
    public List<int> ActorsId { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm thinking of is to insert the data to `Movie` then get the list of ActorId from the dto and insert the data to join table `MovieActor` , I tried doing it by also creating Movie_Actor Model and add it to AppDBContext also mapping it using fluent API as Bellow:

AppDbContext:

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MovieApp.Core.Models;

namespace MovieApp.EF.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie_Actor>()
                .HasOne(m => m.Movie)
                .WithMany(ma => ma.Movie_Actors)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MovieId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie_Actor>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Actor)
                .WithMany(am => am.Movie_Actors)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.ActorId);
        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie_Actor>  movie_Actors { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Movie_Actor Model:

```
 public class Movie_Actor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }

        public int ActorId { get; set; }
        public Actor Actor { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the POST :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(MovieRequestDto dto)
    {
        var movie = new Movie();
        movie.Title = dto.Title;
        movie.Description = dto.Description;
        movie.Genre = dto.Genre;
        movie.ReleasedYear = dto.ReleasedYear;
        movie.PosterUrl = dto.PosterUrl;
        movie.ProducerId = dto.ProducerId;

        await _context.Movies.AddAsync(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        foreach (var ActorId in dto.ActorsId)
        {
            var movie_actor = new Movie_Actor();
            movie_actor.MovieId = movie.Id;
            movie_actor.ActorId = ActorId;

            await _context.movie_Actors.AddAsync(movie_actor);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
```

This way is not working, And I think I don't need to use this way because the EF6 can handle the mapping by it self without doing it manually, So what is the best way to do the CRUD for one to many relation with the latest EF 6.

I'm Getting this Error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'movie_Actors'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:c6f722d2-d86e-453b-8855-da3c87fe20ed
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MovieApp.API.Controllers.MoviesController.Post(MovieRequestDto dto) in C:\Users\AppiaTech-RQab\source\repos\MovieApp\MovieApp.API\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:line 90
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7050
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36
:method: POST
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: https://localhost:7050
Referer: https://localhost:7050/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 158
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Comment: "This way is not working," What is the error?

Comment: Hello @Serge, I Added the response I get, but also the way I'm doing it is for the older version of EF I know that there easer way to accomplish that with EF6.

Comment: Evidently, there's no `movie_Actors` table in the database. How do you create/update the database schema?

Comment: @GertArnold The EF 6 Create a Table in database automatically Called `MovieActor` when there is many to many relation between 2 tables

Comment: If you want an explicit junction table (which makes sense) then both `Actor` and `Movie` must have `ICollection<Movie> MovieActors` and the class name should be `MovieActor`.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to do everytnig in one transaction, otherwise your data integrity can be damaged. Try this

```
        var movie = new Movie();
        movie.Title = dto.Title;
        movie.Description = dto.Description;
        movie.Genre = dto.Genre;
        movie.ReleasedYear = dto.ReleasedYear;
        movie.PosterUrl = dto.PosterUrl;
        movie.ProducerId = dto.ProducerId;
 
        foreach (var ActorId in dto.ActorsId)
        {
            var movie_actor = new Movie_Actor();
            movie_actor.Movie = movie;
            movie_actor.ActorId = ActorId;

           _context.movie_Actors.Add(movie_actor);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

UPDATE

according to your error message you have to map movie_Actors class to a db table too, since apparently they have different names.

Comment: Its not going to work this way because you need to insert the movie first to get its ID and use it in the second Insert.

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha I am sorry but it creates Id automatically when save a new item

Comment: Yes, That's correct if you are inserting data to normal table, but here I'm inserting data to a join table, so you need to insert the `MovieId ` and `ActorId` and both should came from the `Movie` and `Actor` Tables.

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha Thanks for your help, but I've been inserting this way all my life and never had any problems.